# ConnectionAbortedError: [Errno 53] Software caused connection abort

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-multithreading, python-sockets

i am trying to establish connections for multiple sockets using multi-threading

this is the code

```py
import socket as sc
```

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':


    #setup()
    ports = [10000, 10010, 10020, 10030]

    init_sockets()
    init_threads()
```

```py
def init_sockets():

    global host_ip
    global sockets

    host_ip = sc.gethostname()
    sockets = []

    for port in ports:

        socket = sc.socket()
        socket.bind((host_ip, port))
        socket.listen()
        sockets.append(socket)
```

```py
def init_threads():

    threads = [
        threading.Thread(target= init_connection, args= [socket])
        for socket in sockets
    ]

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
```

```py
def init_connection(socket):

    client, address = socket.accept()
```

while running the code this error appears

```
ConnectionAbortedError: [Errno 53] Software caused connection abort
```

the error occurs in `thread.start()` statement in function `init_threads()`

i don't know why this is happening, and would really appreciate any help. i am trying to run multiple socket connections in parallel, if it's impossible this way, i am open to recommendations

Comment: The code seems to be fine. I had an issue with the host name, but changing it to 127.0.0.1 solved it. Make sure one of the ports isn't used by some other application,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it!

the problem seemed to be that when the main thread (program it self) is terminated, all the objects that it created are deleted, including the socket objects.

so when the secondary threads (threads that the main program started), still running, try to reference these deleted objects the error occurs

the solution for me appeared to be adding an infinite `while` loop in the main method. preventing the main thread from being terminated

Comment: Yes, it is customary for the main thread to ‘join()’ all the threads it created.